# Windows 10 - Administrator password wrong when RunAs from a different account

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, administrator

I have a Win 10 VM that I log into using a 365 account that was created before I received the laptop. I am currently unable to install any new software for this user, as when I attempt to use "Run as administrator" it states I have the incorrect password. I know the password is correct as I can log on locally using the Administrator account with the same password.

Any direction on where to look to resolve this issue?

Comment: Try using "use another account" when UAC prompts... it's probably using your other computer/365 domain instead of you specifying the actual VM's hostname. E.g. `VM-Hostname\Administrator`

Comment: Try to check if you could use other software and run it as a different user account to narrow down the issue.